# How to change the attributes of a Tkinter Frame subclass?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

**Context**

I am developing an app with Tkinter in Python 3.8 for some school students, that gets them to input some working out to a maths problem, then checks whether they are correct.

**Approach**

Each widget (or groups of widgets) are organised onto a ttk.Frame subclass, which is then instantiated in a MainWindow class that organises them using the .grid() geometry manager. For example:

```
class Questions(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        question_style = ttk.Style(self)
        question_style.configure("q.TLabel", padding=30)
        question = ttk.Label(self, text=f"{QA[q_number][0]}",
                             justify=tk.CENTER, style="q.TLabel")
        question.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
```

The above Questions class is responsible for displaying the questions. I have taken the same approach for pretty much every widget - navigation buttons, entry fields, etc. I took this approach because I thought it would afford me the greatest design flexibilities, as not only could I change the appearance of each widget, but also the frame on which they were placed (from my experience, school students can be very aesthetically picky).

**Problem**

I cannot figure out how to change the attributes of the Frame on which the widgets are placed. For instance, how would I change the height and width of the frame? I have tried the following, to no avail:

```
class Questions(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.height = 50
        self.width = 50

        question_style = ttk.Style(self)
        question_style.configure("q.TLabel", padding=30)
        question = ttk.Label(self, text=f"{QA[q_number][0]}",
                             justify=tk.CENTER, style="q.TLabel")
        question.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
```

I have also tried `self.configure(height=50)` but that didn't work either.

How can I change the frame on which these widgets are placed?
Is there a better way to tackle this? Should I abandon the Frame subclass approach?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

p.s. I wasn't quite sure how to word this question so any advice on that is also appreciated.

Comment: ***tried `self.configure(height=50)` but that didn't work either.***: That's a valid statement but by default a `Frame` widget shrinks to the size of placed widgets inside, here `Label`, and it depends how you layout the `Frame` which you didn't show us. Read up on [The Tkinter Frame Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm)

Comment: Are you asking how to change any attribute, or are you specifically asking how to change the width and height? Width and height are special, and not something you typically would do. Frames are designed to exactly fit their children and/or exactly fit the space given to them by their parent.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Tkinter much, but have you tried by passing the parameters to the constructor of the superclass?

```
super().__init__(self, width=50, height=50)
```