# tk.TopLevel is making two windows appear, but why?

Tags: python, tk-toolkit

The code below generates my main program (frmMain), which sometimes opens forms. But each time I open a form, the code below makes TWO forms open, the proper form, and one extra one, which is blank. The standard top-right close button only works on the proper form, and, the extra one is invulerable. But why does it appear, and why is it invulnerable?

```
frmMain=tk.Tk()

def createForm():
    lFrm = tk.Toplevel()    #Create a new form
    initForm(lFrm)          #tk.inits the form and sets the mass onFocus event bubble
    return lFrm
    
def initForm(pFrm):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(pFrm) #instead of super
    #super().__init__(master=pFrm)
    setWindowFocusEvent(pFrm) #when any win gets focus, all windows come to fore in order (as per std MDI app behaviour)
```

An example of where I might call this is below, but it causes TWO windows to appear:

```
def listBands():
    global frmMain
    frmMain.lListBandsFrm = createForm()
```

There are some threads on SO about two windows appearing at once, but in those examples I can see what the cause was. But in my case, I really can't. I'm not calling any spurious tk.Tk(), and I'm only calling tk.Toplevel() once for each form. Stepping through the code reveals that both windows appear simultaneously when createForm finishes.

I've tried omitting the **init**() call, but that of course breaks everything, e.g., I can't call .bind until after **init**.

The answer is... not to fiddle with **init**, and to properly use inheritance and subclassing. Here it is:

```
class FrmMDI(tk.Toplevel):  #New form, with my own setup as required
    def __init__(self):     #Autocalled when obj is instantiated
        super().__init__()  #Calls the init() of the parent
        setWindowFocusEvent(self) #My own prep, to improve MDI in Windows

def createForm():      #This was giving me double-windows
    lFrm = FrmMDI()    #Create a new form using subclass of .Toplevel
    return lFrm
```

Comment: `tk.Toplevel.__init__(pFrm)` absolutely does not belong here.  That might be appropriate in the `__init__()` method of a subclass of `Toplevel`, but you have no such thing here.  The instance of `Toplevel` you created was entirely initialized before you assigned it to `lFrm`.  In what way does it "break everything" to omit this line of code?

Comment: I'm testing, early indication is that you're right, and the __init__ isn't required. Last time, I immediately got errors with being unable to call .bind on the form, or to create Tk widgets on the form. Trying to reproduce it at the mo, give us a min & thanks for quick response.

Comment: @VexenCrabtree It's usually a bad idea to try to override the window manager like that (unless you're on Microsoft Windows). That part should probably be a separate question, once you've got this bit working.

Comment: My other forms also call initForm, and /they/ need the __init__, else I can't call .bind() or do most other things on them. The particular error on .bind() is that the form doesn't contain "_w" property, which must be something required by .bind(), but it's internal stuff to Python to Tk. Still investigating and trying to see how I can tell which forms I need to run __init__ on, and which ones I don't.

Comment: I'm not aware I'm overriding any windows manager... but then again, I *am* on Windows...

Comment: @VexenCrabtree The "overriding the window manager" thing was about trying to bring all the windows to the foreground when you select one window. It's incredibly annoying on other operating systems: best to let the window manager handle the windows. (It's only acceptable on Microsoft Windows because overriding it doesn't make it notably worse: it already overrides itself enough that your program isn't going to be _more_ annoying.)

Comment: Ah okay. In the case of Tk on Windows, whenever I select any open Tk window, it only brings that one to the fore. It doesn't do the standard thing of bringing all of the app's windows to the fore. So I'm constantly having to search the task bar to find the app window I want.

So I reproduced the function where if you click on window, all the others come to the fore, in the order they were previously activated. It works well-enough & it much better than not having that feature. That's what setWindowFocusEvent() does. During testing for the prob I'm currently facing, it's actually remmed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is... not to fiddle with **init**, use the built-in and simpler super() instead. It was getting confusing which forms were calling my own custom **init()**, and when I needed to call it. And, rather than write your own Init() that you call from certain forms, it's better to make your own subclass. It then gets easy to understand, and init() works smoothly. Here's those things in code:

```
class FrmMDI(tk.Toplevel):  #New form based on Toplevel, with my own extra setup step
    def __init__(self):     #Autocalled when obj is instantiated
        super().__init__()  #Calls the init() of the parent
        setWindowFocusEvent(self) #My own prep, to improve MDI in Windows

def createForm():      #This was giving me double-windows
    lFrm = FrmMDI()    #Create a new form using subclass of .Toplevel
    return lFrm
```

Comment: For improved extensibility, it's best to put `*args` and `**kwargs` in your `__init__`. (`**kwargs` is most relevant for tkinter. You can open the tkinter/\_\_init__.py file and see how they do it, e.g. on `Widget` subclasses.)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the wonders of `tkinter`'s Default Root… You're creating a root window with your first line. Try running this:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.Tk()
<tkinter.Tk object .>
>>> tkinter.Toplevel()
<tkinter.Toplevel object .!toplevel>
```

The first call creates the main `Tk` window, and the second creates a *new* `Toplevel` window. So… how about removing that first call?

```
RESTART: Shell
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.Toplevel()
<tkinter.Toplevel object .!toplevel>
```

Two windows have appeared! What's going on here? Well, since we haven't created a root window, tkinter creates a root window for us implicitly. You can turn this off by adding a call to `tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()` right at the beginning:

```
RESTART: Shell
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()
>>> tkinter.Toplevel()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    tkinter.Toplevel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2621, in __init__
    BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2566, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2533, in _setup
    master = _get_default_root()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 293, in _get_default_root
    raise RuntimeError("No master specified and tkinter is "
RuntimeError: No master specified and tkinter is configured to not support default root
```

Turns out that tkinter *really wants* to create a default root object. That's because in Tk, everything is part of a hierarchy – even windows. I would suggest one of three workarounds:

- Use a separate `tkinter.Tk` instance for every window, rather than `tkinter.Toplevel` instances. (Simplest, but inelegant.)
- Hide the root window. To ruthlessly steal [from BuvinJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382035/5223757):

  ```py
  root = tkinter.Tk()
  root.overrideredirect(1)
  root.withdraw()
  ```

  (Slightly less inelegant, depending on your use-case.)
- Subclass `tkinter.Frame` instead of `tkinter.Toplevel`, and handle the windowing separately using the `master` keyword. This is my preferred solution, though if you don't know which form will live the longest, you can't make *any* of them the root window, so you'll have to use one of the other two techniques.

---

Note: this isn't *actually* the issue in the question: that issue was duplicate calls to `tkinter.Toplevel.__init__`, which was resolved by subclassing `tkinter.Toplevel` properly. This answer matches the title, though.

Comment: I absolutely need the default root window, and I use it extensively as the program's main window. The main program in future needs to sometimes create new windows, but, those new windows cause 2 to appear, not one, when createForm() is ran.

Comment: @VexenCrabtree That's because you're creating a window, then hackishly initialising another window as a child of it in `initForm` (which only works thanks to an implementation detail). Replace your `initForm` with a proper subclass of `tkinter.Frame` (my third option), and it'll resolve that particular issue without you needing to reorganise your code too much.

Comment: (Sorry, I didn't realise the code in your question was your actual code; I thought it was a buggy simplified example. I might have to move this answer to its own Q&A, because it's answering a different question to the one you asked.)

Comment: @VexenCrabtree Are you familiar with Windows API-like window creation, by any chance? `tkinter` works quite differently to it.

Comment: I am intentionally creating more windows; the application often needs multiple windows opens. Those new windows gain tkinter.Frames of their own.

I'm not familiar with using Windows APIs to create windows... well, not since about 15 years ago. ALmost all Tk apps use .Toplevel to create child windows, as far as I know, it's how it's designed to work.

Comment: @VexenCrabtree Yeah, but arguments like `master=` should be provided when you make the `Toplevel` call: unless you're subclassing (in which case, use `super()`), you should _never_ find yourself calling `__init__` or `__new__` directly. `Toplevel(master=root)` already calls `__init__(newobj, master=root)`: that's how Python works. [See the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization).

Comment: Hopefully something like this is the cause; what exactly do I need to do? (You can see that I used to use super(), but, it currently isn't recognized and/or isn't in context, and won't run in createForm() without error.

Comment: @VexenCrabtree Do you know how to subclass `tkinter.Toplevel` or `tkinter.Frame`? If I were to guess, I'd say that's what the code you've got is _trying_ to do. The first codeblock in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62356478/5223757) provides an example (don't look at the second one: it's confused).

Comment: Here's an example where I do so:

    class FrmTrack(tk.Toplevel):
        def __init__(self, pTrackId=0, pTrackIds=[]):
            global frmMain, glCats, glTracks2, glBands
            initForm(self)

Comment: @VexenCrabtree This is too tricky to fix on Stack Overflow. If it _worked_, I'd suggest sending it over to [codereview.se], but they have a very strict "no buggy code" rule. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256209/discussion-between-wizzwizz4-and-vexen-crabtree).

Comment: I've editted the OP to reflect the answer (last few paras), but if you could edit your proposal so it matches the general gist, then we can delete most of this discussion. I think; whoever has good experience of SO, any advice on how to clear it up for longevity?

Comment: @VexenCrabtree I feel like you should probably post a new answer: mine doesn't actually answer _this_ question, and I don't currently have the capacity to edit it much. Thanks for trying to keep Stack Overflow useful for others! For cleaning up comments: just delete the ones of yours that you think are obsolete, and the others will get deleted too eventually; flag as "No Longer Needed" for a moderator, if you'd like, though that's not necessary in this case because I'll delete my end of them later.